# Jquery datatable getting loaded multiple times in the content section of the table

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery datatable to display data in the table. and on click of row I am calling ajax call and loading data in jquery dialog box.
When i click on search button first and then click on any row then data is loading in dialog popup, and when i close it and click search again then this time along with data jquery datatable wrappers are also getting added to it.

It happens only after i close the dialoge box and search again  Please help

```js
var shipSearchResultTable;
function dataSetup(domain){
 
 if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#shipSearchResultTable' ) ) {
     shipSearchResultTable = $('#shipSearchResultTable').DataTable();
 }
 else {
  if(domain=='GTOCE'){
      shipSearchResultTable = $('#shipSearchResultTable').DataTable( {
          "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
          "scrollY": 350,
          "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "scrollX": true,
    "sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>T',
    "oTableTools": {
              "sSwfPath": "resources/jquery/desktop/js/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
              "aButtons": [
                           "copy",
                           "csv",
                           {
                               "sExtends": "pdf",
                               "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                               "sPdfSize": "A3"
                           },
                           "print"
                       ]
          },
          "language": {
     "emptyTable": "No shipment found"
    },
    "order" : [[ 10, "asc" ]],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sType": "date", "aTargets": [10] }],
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
              $(nRow).click( function() {
               
          });
      } 
      } );
  }else{
   shipSearchResultTable = $('#shipSearchResultTable').DataTable( {
          "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
          "scrollY": 350,
          "bJQueryUI" : true,
    "scrollX": true,
    "sDom": '<"H"lfr>t<"F"ip>T',
    "oTableTools": {
              "sSwfPath": "resources/jquery/desktop/js/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
              "aButtons": [
                           "copy",
                           "csv",
                           {
                               "sExtends": "pdf",
                               "sPdfOrientation": "landscape",
                               "sPdfSize": "A3"
                           },
                           "print"
                       ]
          },
          "language": {
     "emptyTable": "No shipment found"
    },
    "order" : [[ 4, "asc" ]],
    "aoColumnDefs": [{ "sType": "date", "aTargets": [4] }],
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex ) {
              $(nRow).click( function() {
               
          });
      } 
      } );
  }
 }

 $('#shipSearchResultTable tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
  if(shipSearchResultTable.context[0].aoData.length > 0){    
   if (! $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
           shipSearchResultTable.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
              $(this).addClass('selected');
          }
   showSpinnerWheel();
   if(domain=='GTOCE'){
          loadShipDetailPopup($('td', this).eq(0).text(), $('td', this).eq(11).text());
   }else{
    loadShipDetailPopup($('td', this).eq(0).text(), $('td', this).eq(5).text());
   }
         }
     } );

 $( "#date_from,#date_to" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "date picker",
    prevText: "",
    nextText: "",
    buttonImage: "resources/jquery/desktop/images/calendar.gif",
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    defaultDate: new Date()
   });
 $('#submitBtn').on( 'click', function () {
  showSpinnerWheel();
  getSearchResultData(domain);
 } );
} 
 
function loadShipDetailPopup(shipmentNumber, loadNumber){
 $("#shipDetPopup").dialog({
  modal: true,
  autoOpen: false,
     autoResize: true,
     hide: "fold",
     title:'Shipment Details',
     position: 'center' ,
     maxHeight: 1000,
     open: function(event, ui) { $(this).css({"max-height": 1000, "overflow-y": "auto"}); },
     resizable: true,
     show: "fadeIn",
     position: { my: "center top", at:"center top", of: window },
     width: 1000
 });
  $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "shipment_detail.st",
         data: {shpm_num:shipmentNumber, ld_leg_id: loadNumber}
   }).done(function(data) {
    $("#shipDetPopup").load($(data)).dialog("open");
    $("#shipDetPopupContent").html(data);
    hideSpinnerWheel();
   }); 
}

function getSearchResultData(domain){
 var id = "ship_search_form";
  shipSearchResultTable = $('#shipSearchResultTable').dataTable();
 var values = $("#"+id).serialize();
 $.ajax( {
  type: "GET",
        url: "search_list_desktop.st",
        data: values,
  success : function(response) {
  
   if (response.status == "SUCCESS") {
    var resultLength = response.result.length;
    shipSearchResultTable.fnClearTable();
    if(domain == "GTOCE"){
    for ( var i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
     var shipSearchResultData = [];
     
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].number)); 
     if(response.result[i].loadStatus == 5220){
      shipSearchResultData.push("<img width='20' height='20' src='resources/images/icon-shp-status-"+statusKeyMap['ship.load.status.'+response.result[i].loadStatus+'.short']+".png' /> "+statusKeyMap['ship.load.status.'+response.result[i].loadStatus+'.long']);
     }else if(response.result[i].loadStatus == 5210){
      shipSearchResultData.push("<img width='20' height='20' src='resources/images/icon-shp-status-"+statusKeyMap['ship.load.status.'+response.result[i].loadStatus+'.short']+".png' /> "+statusKeyMap['ship.load.status.'+response.result[i].loadStatus+'.long']);
     }else{
      shipSearchResultData.push("<img width='20' height='20' src='resources/images/icon-shp-status-"+statusKeyMap['ship.status.'+response.result[i].statusCode+'.short']+".png' /> "+statusKeyMap['ship.status.'+response.result[i].statusCode+'.long']);
     }
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].originLocation));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].originLocationName));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].orgCityName));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].orgCntryCd));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].destinationLocation));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].destinationLocationName));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].destCityName));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].destCntryCd));
     shipSearchResultData.push(response.result[i].expectedDeliveryDate);
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].loadNumber));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].loadTrackingNo));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].carrierName));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].trailerNumber));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].equpimentDesc));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].serviceType));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].orderType));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].consigneeLocation));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].authorizationNumber));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].toReferenceNumber));
     
     var row = shipSearchResultTable.fnAddData(shipSearchResultData);
     var nTr = shipSearchResultTable.fnSettings().aoData[ row[0] ].nTr;
     nTr.style.color = response.result[i].priority;
     
    }
   }else{
    for ( var i = 0; i < resultLength; i++) {
     var shipSearchResultData = [];
     
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].number)); 
     if(response.result[i].loadStatus == 5220){
      shipSearchResultData.push("<img width='20' height='20' src='resources/images/icon-shp-status-"+statusKeyMap['ship.load.status.'+response.result[i].loadStatus+'.short']+".png' /> "+statusKeyMap['ship.load.status.'+response.result[i].loadStatus+'.long']);
     }else if(response.result[i].loadStatus == 5210){
      shipSearchResultData.push("<img width='20' height='20' src='resources/images/icon-shp-status-"+statusKeyMap['ship.load.status.'+response.result[i].loadStatus+'.short']+".png' /> "+statusKeyMap['ship.load.status.'+response.result[i].loadStatus+'.long']);
     }else{
      shipSearchResultData.push("<img width='20' height='20' src='resources/images/icon-shp-status-"+statusKeyMap['ship.status.'+response.result[i].statusCode+'.short']+".png' /> "+statusKeyMap['ship.status.'+response.result[i].statusCode+'.long']);
     }
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].originLocation)+", "+(response.result[i].orgCityName)+" ,"+(response.result[i].orgStateCd));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].destinationLocation)+", "+(response.result[i].destCityName)+" ,"+(response.result[i].destStateCd));
     
     shipSearchResultData.push(response.result[i].expectedDeliveryDate);
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].loadNumber));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].loadTrackingNo));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].carrierName));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].trailerNumber));
     shipSearchResultData.push((response.result[i].equpimentDesc));
          
     var row = shipSearchResultTable.fnAddData(shipSearchResultData);
     var nTr = shipSearchResultTable.fnSettings().aoData[ row[0] ].nTr;
     nTr.style.color = response.result[i].priority;
     
    }
   }

   } else {
    document.getElementById("jpt_err").style.display = 'block';
   }
  },
  error : function(e) {
   document.getElementById("jpt_err").style.display = 'block';
  }
 }

 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after doing lot of debug I found that data table which was getting added inside, on every submit was due to multiple direct initialization of the data table at wrong places.

data table initialization should be handled globally. I used below code to avoid the problem in function getSearchResultData(domain)

```
if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#shipSearchResultTable' ) ) {
     shipSearchResultTable = $('#shipSearchResultTable').dataTable();
    }
```

Thought this might help others also